# Can't understand iPhone crash log

Tags: iphone, ios

I've two crash logs and I can't understand reason for that. Both almost the same:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x382de3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3716a95e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x382de302 +[NSException raise:format:] + 102
3   RogApp                          0x00101eea +[UAirship shared] (UAirship.m:320)
4   RogApp                          0x0012d3ea -[UAEvent addDataFromSessionWithKey:forKey:] (UAEvent.m:96)
5   RogApp                          0x0012d44a -[UAEvent addDataFromSessionForKey:] (UAEvent.m:100)
6   RogApp                          0x0012da1e -[UAEventAppExit gatherIndividualData:] (UAEvent.m:230)
7   RogApp                          0x0012d520 -[UAEvent gatherData:] (UAEvent.m:114)
8   RogApp                          0x0012d1a0 -[UAEvent initWithContext:] (UAEvent.m:57)
9   RogApp                          0x0012d1cc +[UAEvent eventWithContext:] (UAEvent.m:64)
10  RogApp                          0x00101e0a +[UAirship land] (UAirship.m:302)
11  RogApp                          0x0002ff34 -[RAAppDelegate applicationWillTerminate:] (RAAppDelegate.m:179)
12  UIKit                           0x3764fd9e -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 130
13  UIKit                           0x3764c650 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 2200
14  UIKit                           0x375c229c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2464
15  UIKit                           0x375c1778 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
16  UIKit                           0x375c11ba _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
17  GraphicsServices                0x3555f5f2 _PurpleEventCallback + 586
18  GraphicsServices                0x3555f222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
19  CoreFoundation                  0x382b33e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
20  CoreFoundation                  0x382b3386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
21  CoreFoundation                  0x382b220a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
22  CoreFoundation                  0x38225238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
23  CoreFoundation                  0x382250c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
24  GraphicsServices                0x3555e336 GSEventRunModal + 70
25  UIKit                           0x3761528c UIApplicationMain + 1116
26  RogApp                          0x0002f7fa main (main.m:17)
27  RogApp                          0x0002f774 0x2d000 + 10100RogApp
```

Between

```
26  RogApp                          0x0002f7fa main (main.m:17)
```

and

```
11  RogApp                          0x0002ff34 -[RAAppDelegate applicationWillTerminate:] (RAAppDelegate.m:179)
```

there is no any calls to my code

In RAAppDelegate I've:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [UAirship land];
}
```

So why app terminated when it in foreground? Is it related to system conditions?
Thanks

Comment: You left out only the essential part of the crash log. What is the error message (i. e. the reason for the `NSException`)?

Comment: If there's no NSException thrown, try catching it manually in main.m @try{/* Code from main.m*/ } @catch(NSException *exception) {NSLog(@"%@", exception);}

Comment: Problem is that this crash log is only thing that I have. I dont know error message. Also If I understand correctly, this exception raised in CoreFoundation when app is terminated. But why app terminated?

Comment: Have you tried catching NSException ? Sometimes, there's no error message, but when you try catching it, you may get it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant replicate this crash, so I cant see log in xCode. But I'll try to do that. Hope this helps. Thanks for your answer